# Plugging/configuring second monitor causes logout

Tags: kubuntu, 15.10, qt, plasma-5, kde5

When I plug an additional screen to my laptop while the OS is running, there are mainly no problems. But:

- when I move one of the screens to the other side of the second one in System Settings, the system logs out.
- if I at first put one screen above the other and then set them as I wanted to, everything is ok.
- if I run the system with both screens plugged, logging in through X is impossible: entering the password returns me back to the login screen.
- logging out always makes the system forget the screens' settings.

These sometimes crash KDE (Plasma?) so much, that problem no. 3 appears always, even with the second screen plugged off. I managed to repair this case by removing the `~/.Xauthority` file, but I'm not happy to do this all time. I have tried to remove `~/.local/share/kscreen` files, clear  `~/.cache`, `~/.kde`, but with no results.

I am using Kubuntu 15.10 (the lastest one)  with KDE 5. I have an NVIDIA graphics card.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and the way I've partially solved (as in it works most of the time, but not always) is by doing this after the forced logout:

1. Unplug the second screen.
2. Login.
3. Open a terminal and run:

   ```
   rm .config/monitors.xml
   ```

   This removes the previously saved monitor configuration.
4. Open Screen Display.
5. Without changing any setting, just press *Apply*.
6. Move the monitors to the setting you want, press *Apply*.
7. You'll get an error dialog box, press *OK*.

Most of the time this works for me, until I reboot or power off. Then I have to repeat these steps all over again.

Comment: At which step should it be plugged in? I may be having the same issue as you right now.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully OP resolved the issue as this might come in late but I'm just putting this here as others may encounter similar issue.

I encountered the same issue when i plugged in the additional monitors. No matter how I tried to sign in, I kept getting logged out. Only when i unplugged the monitors then am i able to sign in and enter the system. I suspected it might been due to the graphic card settings as i previously changed the prime-select settings to nvidia to make sure that I was able to use my dedicated NVIDIA graphic card as I have a AMD/NVIDIA graphic cards combo.

Hence, what i did was to change the prime select option to on-demand and this problem resolved for me.

`$ sudo prime-select on-demand`

The system I am using is Ubuntu 20.04 with integrated AMD Radeon 680M Graphics and dedicated NVIDIA 3070 Ti Graphics. Hopefully this might work for whoever that encountered this problem!